# IE background image works in some cases, but doesn't load in the other cases

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have recently setup my caching through apache `mod-expires` and `mod-headers`.

I noticed that afterwards, my website in IE doesn't show some of the images.

### Here is what it looks like in IE :

[image]

### In Chrome or Firefox, it looks like this (and this is what it should look like) :

[image]

I have tried clearing the cache but it doesn't seem to work.

Before I have set up the caching, everything seems to work fine. Although I'm not sure how it should be related to this issue.

Additional details :

Here is the code for that certain div :

```
<a href="/index.php/component/alfrescocontent/?nodeid=2a06a549-b96e-490e-ae03-dcebfa293cc7">
  <h2 class="h2-a span-h2-normal">Libraries and Museums</h2>

  <div style="background-image: url('http://www.melvillecity.com.au/newproxy/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/5c6ed0dd-cb7d-49d4-8274-b8909f58794e/Libraries.jpg/content/Libraries.jpg?alf_ticket=TICKET_f0f806846fe0fb62376597a12daf0684015e4dc8'); width:200px;height:100px; ">

  </div>
</a>
```

---

[Here](http://www.melvillecity.com.au/Community+%252526+Facilities) is the URL if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: What do you mean? Why Google Maps is loaded? It's used in some of the pages, which doesn't include this one.

Comment: I didn't see that! I'm sorry. I'm not sure I even tagged anything. Lol.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @MarkGabriel - [I get this user/pass request](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AiKdQ.png) when I try and view Libraries.jpg

Comment: @Vucko, absolutely no errors in IE or Chrome or Firefox. As you can see in IE, each of the divs have the same code, but some of them load the image just fine.

Comment: @misterManSam, that's because each image request is dependent on your session ID (don't ask me why). Try going to http://www.melvillecity.com.au/Community+%252526+Facilities on IE to see for yourself.

Comment: @MarkGabriel - I don't know how this makes a difference, but you will note that each image that *is working* has "[Name] Thumbnail.jpg" (note the space). The **non-working** images have "[Name]-1.jpg". I don't know what this means, but it is a pattern.